# How to fix the firebase signup authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm creating an apps for my final year project. So i want to use login and signup features. But when i enter the details of the signup, its keep fail and do not direct the data to the firebase.

```
    Signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validate()){
                String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();

                firebase.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Signup successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this, LoginPage.class));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Signup failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

So, is there anything that i have to change?

Comment: what does the logcat say?

Comment: **W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.**

The logcat said this

Comment: Thank you! Im really sorry. I didnt saw that. Again, im sorry. Plus, im new here. So i need an exposure about this.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to initialize the FirebaseAuth object

`FirebaseAuth firebase = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

and Enable the email method in Firebase console

Comment: I already initialize both of firebaseauth object and enable the email method in firebase console

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you enabled email as an authentication method on firebase portal authentication section.

Comment: Already done it